# What constraints does associativity put on a real function $f(x, y)$?

Tags: soft-question, graphing-functions, associativity

We are familiar with the algebraic meaning of associativity.
But suppose we have a real function $f(x, y)$.
What constraints does
$$
f(f(x,y),z) = f(x,f(y,z))
\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
put on $f$?
Can they be visualised as certain symmetries of (the graph of) $f$, or understood in any other way which isn’t (obviously) just a restatement of \eqref{1}?

For instance, commutativity $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$ is reflection-symmetry of the graph of $f$ across the diagonal $x=y$.
Linearity of $f$ means that the graph is a (sloped, non-vertical) plane crossing the origin.

Comment: How so? My question is about what we can say about a function $f : ℝ^2 → ℝ$ given that it is associative, apart from that eq. $(1)$ holds — e.g., what we can tell visually about the plot of $f$.

Comment: If it's a power series, this is called a [formal group law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_group_law).

Comment: It seems like if $f$ is required to be [rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function), then up to a change of variables $f(x,y)$ is one of $x$, $y$, $x+y$, or $x+y+xy$. See [here](http://www.math.clemson.edu/~sgao/papers/associate.pdf)

Comment: Every group of order continuum and every permutation of $\Bbb R$ give one $f$. If you do not require some form of continuity, you won't get any info.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Interesting — are there any associative non-rational real functions of two variables?

Comment: @Jollywatt, of course. Fix your favorite group $(G, \star)$ of size $|\mathbb{R}|$. Then there's a bijection $\varphi : G \to \mathbb{R}$, and the function $f(x,y) = \varphi \left ( \varphi^{-1}(x) \star \varphi^{-1} (y) \right)$ will be an associative function on $\mathbb{R}$. This is what markvs was mentioning. Of course, the graph of this function will be hideous (by which I mean undrawable). Likely what you want to ask is whether there's a nice geometric characterization of functions which are both associative and continuous.

Comment: I'm not sure if there are associative, continuous, nonrational functions (though I suspect the answer is "yes"), which is why I only left a comment

Comment: Wouldn't $f(x,y) = (\sqrt[3]{x} + \sqrt[3]{y})^3$ give an example of an associative, continuous, nonrational function?